# blender renders nothing

Tags: objects, blender-internal-render-engine

i've made a bus model for my little project, on the earlier version of my model it renders just fine, on this version it just doesn't show up in the renderer, just pitch black,on materials and texture its fine, render just shows nothing, here's a screenshot and my .blend file that might help you to understand my problem
[image]

[image]

Comment: There seem to be no lamps in your scene

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Object renders black](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57036/object-renders-black)

Comment: no its not like that, its a different case, and for lamps there is actually plenty, its just below the cylinder in the items list, and you can see there is visible lights reflecting on top of the bus at the material view so no, its a different one i think

Comment: The .blend file link doesn't work.

Comment: See if any of the possible causes for blank rendering applies in your case: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/53633/1853

Comment: For future questions please use only the "official" upload service http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ . Files on other services tend to "vanish" over time, thus making the question and possible answers eventually less useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You turned off the *Combined* Layer Pass in the scene

Go to the *Properties Editor > Render Layers Tab > Passes* and activate the *Combined* layer pass