# For somereason when I render my intro, there's just black, how can I fix this?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, text-object

So I am right making my first intro, and I finished, I then rendered it, but when I watched the video it was completely black, so I went back into blender to try to fix it, I then checked what the text looked like, this is what I got (Picture down below)

[image]

The text is supposed to be blue, but it comes out black, and since the background is transparent, it will just show a black void when rendered, if anyone can find a solution to my problem I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Object renders black](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57036/object-renders-black)

Comment: This has been asked over and over and over again. Just search for [render black](http://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=Render+black)  and go through all the solutions until it works