# same material, one is darker

Tags: materials

I've a simple scene with two objects with the same material. 
Strangely, one of them is darker and I just can't figure it out why. 
No it's not their normals, I've already checked it.

Here's the scene:
[image]

Normals:
[image]

They don't have any textures. The worst is, if I export it into unity, the problem persists, so clearly something is wrong here, I just don't know what.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps duplicated faces?

Comment: Can you please add a blend file?

Comment: It's hard to see many details of the lighting, so this may not be the answer,  but one thing that can cause this phenomenon is if one copy is in the shadow of the other.

Comment: It was an fbx file I converted to blender. My only guess is that something might went wrong, but I really don't know.

Comment: Those are custom split normals, so either remove them or uncheck AutoSmooth, related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57036/object-renders-black

Comment: Ah, thanks! I'd never figured it out on my own!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a comment by mr-zac

> Those are custom split normals.
>   Either remove them, or uncheck AutoSmooth.

Comment: @cegaton Its community wiki... I can add in who wrote the comment if you wish

Comment: @cegaton I see. I thought that posting it as community wiki was good enough.