# Why is my rendered textured mesh showing up as black?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, texturing

For some reason when I render (via cycles) my textured mesh shows up as black. I have a UV mapping setup on the mesh, a light source, and a set of nodes describing the material. When viewing through texture mode it shows the texture just fine

[image: Rendered mesh]

[image: Textured mesh]

**Edit** Uploaded .blend file
[image]

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/57042/37728

Comment: ty, the solutions there seem to be: add a light source, and turn off auto smoothing. Neither of those seem to be the issue here. I believe the normals are fine, and I do have a light source (added multiple to test, just in case)

Comment: hey since you're not using toon, how about just disconnecting it from diffuse all together?
try not using texture coordinate but use uv map instead? good luck! let me know what works for you if those don't work.

Comment: If it's possible, [upload](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) the blend file with problem project and include link here. Unconnected node won't affect the result like that just likely as Texture Coordinate node.

Comment: Uploaded .blend file. Also packed the texture image into the file

Comment: Your UV map needs to be cleaned up and you need more light, but it looks green on my machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that packing the image into the blend file was enough to get it to render correctly. Its strange because it was clearly able to read the image file, given that it was showing up in my UV/Image editor. I'm not entirely sure what the root cause of the issue was